# Texture Address Mode Clamping, how does it work?

Tags: opengl, textures, mode

I'm trying to understand how texture clamping works in OpenGL or any other API for that matter. I am aware of the fact that you define the operation as extending the range from [0,1] to anything, but clamping it to the edge.

So, if I have a pseudocode function:

`unsigned int clampedTexel(float u, float v)

{

if(u < 0) u = 0;

if(u >= width) u = width-1;

if(v < 0) v = 0;

if(v >= height) v = height-1;

return image[u][v];`

}

[image]
<sub>(source: [sud at wwwx.cs.unc.edu](http://wwwx.cs.unc.edu/%7Esud/courses/236/a6/small/tex_0_clamp.png))</sub>

Right? So, If I run out of range, like 1.1 in the u direction, why doesn't it get clamped to the black color which is at the end? Rather than black, it goes to white in this example. Have I misunderstood something? Why is the value next to black getting clamped to white?

Or any other extension which is alternating from the edge color.
Help me see where I am failing, please.

Comment: Basically, if u is bigger than 1, it's 1. Same for v. And same for less than 0 on u and v. But only the big black void makes sense ( 1.5, 1.5 would be 1.0 and 1.0 which is black.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think I see the problem.  You're overlooking the fact that the top row of the texture is really the "white/black" alternating line, not the "black/white" line it appears to be.  So the top row repeating white/black is correct.  A similar situation occurs on the right edge where the last column is repeating white/black down rather than black/white.

Here is your texture with its outline:

[image]

Comment: I've changed the ascii art to his initial image. I hope you don't mind ?

Comment: Thanks, it helps the explanation.  I worry vaguely about the image becoming unavailable at some point but there's nothing for it.  Too bad stack overflow doesn't host images, too.

Comment: meta discussion, but I used SO's upload. hopefully they use a service they have a relationship of some sort with!

Comment: Oh, thank you! That was so ambiguous for me. Makes a lot of sense now, thanks! I actually devised my own calculation for obtaining that result, taking the half of the width of the texture and 1 - the half-height of the texture in the selected heading. That seemed logical when I didn't know this "revelation" (at least for me). 

Many thanks, mate! I feel better now!